# nginx: django template index.html can't display well

Tags: django, nginx

I have a Django project and the main structure of it like this

```
proj/
  + main/
     + templates/
     |  + index.html
     |  + header.html
     |  + navbar.html
     |  + ...
     + other files
     + ...
  + another_app/
  + ...
```

And the `index.html` includes `navbar.html` and `navbar.html`. 
Then I use gunicorn and nginx to serve it public. However, the index page doesn't display properly. And it contains the Django template syntax like this:

```
{% include 'header.html' %} {% include 'navbar.html' %}
Title
```

I am not quite sure why this happens.

Here is my Nginx conf for the project:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name proj.app;
    root "/home/vagrant/proj/main";

    index index.html index.htm;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        root "/home/vagrant/proj/main/templates";
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.htm;
     }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/proj.app-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location /static {
        alias "/home/vagrant/proj/main/static";
    }

    location /media  {
        alias "/home/vagrant/proj/main/media";
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I have tried to use upstream modele or use server gunicorn.sock when proxy_pass, but that is still not working. Can someone give me a hint about this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something big here. Why is your webserver configuration relevant to an issue with your template files? Your webserver should (almost) never server your template files directly, they should be processed by Django.

Comment: yes, that might be the point. I am trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

You've configured nginx to serve the template directly. I'm not sure why you've done that, but clearly doing so will bypass Django completely, so the template will be served as raw HTML and will not be parsed.

Solution: don't do that.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the point. I am going to find some ways to pass to the Django.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about how to pass to the Django? I am little confused about this.

Comment: You need to write a Django view, and set nginx to forward / rather than /api to the upstream server.